# "can grow" proprity of a crystal report field doesn't push down lines correctly

Tags: crystal-reports

In my CR report i wanted to draw a Table so i used : **Lines & Boxes**.

But some of my fields contains a lot of information, so i had to change the **"Can Grow"** propriety of certain field to **True**, now the fields can wrap to Multi lines, **but they don't push down the lines**.

*IN THE IMAGE: The Highlighted (Green) line is the actual position of the line (you can see that it hasn't being pushed down), The red line shows the right position where it is suppose to be.*

***How can i make "Can Grow" propriety in crystal report pushes down the lines ?***

[image: My report]

Comment: Where did you place the line? Same section or different section

Answer (score 18, accepted):

i finally found the answer :

The Line needs to be placed in a **different Detail Section**.

You need to **split the details section into two parts (Details Section a, and b)**, one that contains the Field and the other under contains the Line, this way doesn't matter how big is the upper one (The one containing the Text) the Section containing the line will always remain under.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Actually you can put the line on the same section instead of creating a different section just for the line.

What you need to do is the following

1. Right click > Format Line
2. Check "Move to Bottom of Section when Printing"

[image: Move line to bottom]

Then your line will always be pushed down to the bottom of the section if your field grows.

Comment: I think this should be marked as the right answer.