# Is there any way to show fields of crystal report on same page if there is space on that page?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, crystal-reports

I am retrieving data of 6 fields of 1 person and showing in report. Problem is if there are few number of lines of text in field1 then field1 will be shown in page1 but if text consists of too many lines then whole field1 will be displayed on page 2 and page1 will look empty. I want to display field1 text on page1 that fits on that page and remaining text on next page.

Comment: you can use 'Can Grow' property of that fields. Just right click and you will get this property

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'Can Grow' and for page content there is setting as here. Also you need to add a section if your text is dynamic and expandable.

http://docs.imis.com/15.2/index.htm#!tipsandtrickscrystalreports.htm

["can grow" proprity of a crystal report field doesn't push down lines correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28045209/can-grow-proprity-of-a-crystal-report-field-doesnt-push-down-lines-correctly)